# Can't save bitmap: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, file, bitmap, io

I try to save a bitmap, but the line `outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);` always throws the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/inpaint/card.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.

```
    //Save bitmap
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    File f3=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/inpaint/");
    if(!f3.exists())
        f3.mkdirs();
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/inpaint/"+"card"+".png");
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outStream);
        outStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also added

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

to the manifest.

Comment: Does your device run in Android MM or above ?

Comment: I target API 15 and higher.

Comment: Alright, but what is the android os version of the device in which your app is running? If it is  >= marshmallow then you have to ask permission on run-time.

Comment: `f3.mkdirs();`. Check the return value as it might fail to create the directory. In that case display a toast telling the user this. And return. Do not continue with the code as it makes little sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply the following code -

```
final int MyVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (MyVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                                if (!checkIfAlreadyhavePermission()) {
                                   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(YourActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                                } else {
                                    your_method();
                                }
                                } else {
                                    your_method();
                            }

private void your_code(){
      //Your entire code will go here
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    your_method();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide access to external storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not change anything. I update my question.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Your accepted answer didn't tell what to do when user presses "Allow" or "Deny" button. You need to handle this on OnRequestPermissionResult() method. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

If your device is contain marshmallow then give permission run time :

```
       private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

            requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    }
```

Pass bitmap in below method :

```
          public void CaptureImage(Bitmap bitmap) {

    try {
        File imageFile;
        File dir;


        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FolderName");

        boolean success = true;
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            success = dir.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
            imageFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator
                    + new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString()
                    + "Image.jpg");

            imageFile.createNewFile();
        } else {
            return;
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // save image into gallery
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        fout.write(ostream.toByteArray());
        fout.close();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the same problem with me. In android Version 23 or Above, you need to ask users for extra storage permission in codes. Details explain in below link.

http://www.androidhowtocode.com/2017/01/javaiofilenotfoundexception.html

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. This error message gave me no clue this was missing...

Comment: Link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can save image in picture folder using this single line and pass your bitmap below line:

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Detected Image", "");